# Kernel_size for rgb images in cnn?

Tags: neural-networks, image-processing, convolution, image-segmentation

I came across a cnn code of rgb images where kernel_size was mentioned only 3 not 3,3,3. So does 3 means 3,3,3. and for greyscale images kernel size was mentioned 3,3 so for grey scale images 3,3 I understood but I am confused about rgb images that have only 3? Code is below:[image: Code]